# How to calculate HCF a very large number and a small number without causing stack overflow. I am using euclid algorithm

Tags: c++

I am using Euclid algorithm but it is causing run time error due to stack overflow.
I am unable to calculate HCF of a very large number and a small number

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using at the moment?

Comment: Use an iterative approach rather than recursive. If you want a more detailed answer, you are going to need to provide an [mcve].

Comment: Stack overflow??? What's your recursive function? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Please provide code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Correctly implemented algorithm shall use at most log(number) steps, and thus not cause stack overflow. I suppose you use the following algorithm:

```
gcd(a, 0) = a
gcd(a, b) = gcd(a-b, b)
```

which looks like this in C++:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0) {
    return a;
  } else {
    return gcd(std::max(a, b) - std::min(a, b), std::min(a, b));
  }
}
```

This is not optimal. Instead  you shall use the following relation

```
gcd(a, 0) = a
gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a mod b)
```

which looks like this in C++:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0) {
    return a;
  } else {
    return gcd(b, a % b);
  }
}
```

This code will actually take only log(ab) steps, and thus not cause stack overflow

Also you may try to enable optimisation: it should allow to collapse both of the functions call into non-recursive versions (as this is a [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)). Note that it is not certain if it will increase speed.

As a matter of caution: be careful with the negative numbers, the % operator works incorrectly for them

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're writing a function like this:

```
int hcf(int a, int b){
    if (a == 0){
        return b;
    }
    else if (b == 0){
        return a;
    }
    else if (a > b){
        return hcf(b, a - b); // this is subtraction
    }
    else if (a < b){
        return hcf(a, a - b); // this is subtraction
    }
}
```

...and you're calling it with something like

```
int q = hcf(100000000, 1);
```

Well... Without optimisation that will create **1 billion** recursion calls. It's definite that your program will run out of stack capacity.

My personally preferred solution is **give up recursive methods and use an iterative one**. The code can then be simplified to a single loop:

```
int hcf(int a, int b){
    while(a != 0 && b != 0){
        if (a > b){
            a = a - b;
        }
        else{
            b = b - a;
        }
    }
    if (a == 0){
        return b;
    }
    else{
        return a;
    }
}
```

If you insist on using recursive methods, **replace subtraction with modulus**.

```
    else if (a > b){
->      return hcf(b, a % b); // this is modulus
    }
    else if (a < b){
->       return hcf(a, a % b); // this is modulus
    }
```